# Really really unmodify a directory in git

Tags: git

I ran `git commit -a`, and it picked up a change to a ruby gem I didn't touch intentionally. Heres the result of `git status`

```
Changes not staged for commit:
(use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
(use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

modified:   api/gems/file_service (new commits)
```

What I want is to make that file exactly how it is on origin, so that Im not commiting any changes to it.

I tried:

```
git pull —rebase master
git fetch; git reset --hard origin/master
```

But git status still shows the same thing. Also:

```
git checkout -- api/gems/file_service
```

But still: `modified:   api/gems/file_service (new commits)`

I thought these commands were supposed to wipe any local changes I had to the directory. Why does git still think something is changed in there?

Comment: Maybe because line endings are changed. Some comparison tools by default ignore them, so you think the file is unchanged.

Comment: @3615 Why would it matter? Shouldn't git checkout -- <file> reset the file completely? Why would it reset everything about a file except for line endings?

Comment: `api/gems/file_service` looks like a submodule. Try running `git submodule update`.

Comment: @jsageryd You got it. Go ahead and make that an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: Nice that it worked out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`api/gems/file_service` looks like a submodule. Try running `git submodule update` to check out the commit that the superproject expects.

More info at [man git-submodule](https://gitirc.eu/git-submodule.html).